# Finding the number of pagination buttons in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pagination

Pagination is itself a last row of table "ContentPlaceHolder1_gvChannelList".
I want to count the number of pages/number of columns in pagination table.

```
driver.findElements(By.id("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_gvChannelList']/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td")).size()
```

Is returning 0 though there are five columns/`<td>` tags.

[html table element hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCvCK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are searching by Id, but you gave xpath expression. Try

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_gvChannelList']/tbody/tr[17]/td/table/tbody/tr/td")).size()
```

Comment: Corrected the expression. Working fine. Thanks